# Need Help with RunScheduleTask to automate a camera snapshots

Tags: programming, image-processing, image

I need help with this application. I want to automate a Device camera to capture images to a List  using ScheduledTask.

I know there must be other ways to automate a task in Mathematica, but this is the one that I consider will provide control of each image capture with other environmental variables surrounding the picture at each instance. In this code, I want to capture the AbsoluteTime.

Here is my work.  I am trying to capture 10 images every 3 seconds.THe image is to be added to a list

```
 snapshots = {};
dev = DeviceOpen["Camera"]
DeviceRead[dev]
AppendTo[snapshots, DeviceRead[dev]]
RunScheduledTask[
 AppendTo[snapshots, {DeviceRead[dev], AbsoluteTime[]}], {1, 10}]
snapshots
```

The code is picking up a first image, but is not adding the other 9. Another issue is that the camera is not turning off after executing the RunScheduleTask. I used DeviceClose[] but this ends the program in the first image capture.

Comment: Ten images every three seconds, or one image every three seconds ten times? Your code seems to say that you want to capture one image every second, ten times.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out to me. I want 10 shots taken every 3 seconds apart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution #1:

```
Clear[photos]
camera = DeviceOpen["Camera"];
takePhoto[] := DeviceRead[camera]

photos = {takePhoto[]};
Dynamic[photos]

RunScheduledTask[Set[photos, Join[photos, {takePhoto[]}]], 3];
RunScheduledTask[
  {RemoveScheduledTask[ScheduledTasks[]],DeviceClose["Camera"]},
  {30}];
```

Solution #2

```
takePhotos[interval_, n_] := Module[{photos},
  takePhoto[dev_] := {DeviceRead[dev], DateList[]};
  camera = DeviceOpen["Camera"];
  photos = 
   Join[{takePhoto[]}, 
    Table[(Pause[interval]; takePhoto[camera]), n - 1]];
  DeviceClose["Camera"];
  photos]
takePhotos[3, 10]
```

Comment: Thank you but is not quite doing what I need. I need 10 images taken 3 seconds apart. Also this code is dropping an error.

Comment: I have adjusted the interval.

Answer (score 3):

You can take a bunch of shots with [`DeviceReadList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeviceReadList.html). Fore more efficient appending, I use an [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) and have each snap associated with the time when it was taken.

```
ClearAll[camera, photos, snaps, task];

camera = DeviceOpen["Camera"];

photos = <||>;

snaps[n_Integer?NonNegative] := Association[
   Table[DateObject[] -> DeviceRead[camera, "Camera"], n]];

task = RunScheduledTask[photos = Join[photos, snaps[10]], 3];
```

I didn't attempt to have photos updated dynamically, which seems like it wouldn't be necessary for many use cases. When you get sick of taking pics, you can end it with

```
RemoveScheduledTask@task;
```

You can retrieve the pics from `photos` directly using `Values@photos`. Each photo will have a time stamp ([`DateObject`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateObject.html)) which you can examine programmatically using ([`DateValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateValue.html))

Comment: This looks good. But I really need to have the time attached to each image. I need 10 images taken 3 sec apart.